# Ada: attribute 'last and 'safe_large

Tags: attributes, numbers, ada

it's very common in Ada to create a derived type say a new Float type with the last element being Float'Last. I have not yet seen someone using Float'Safe_Large instead of the attribute Float'Last when defining a new Float type. On my 32-bit machine, both

```
Put( Float'Image( Float'Last ));
```

and

```
Put( Float'Image( Float'Safe_large ));
```

return me the value 3.402..E38

I would like to know the difference between these two number attributes and perhaps also why 'Safe_Large is not as commonly used as the attribute 'Last.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, the [`Last`](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-K.html) attribute is defined for any scalar subtype. Now obsolete, [`Safe_Large`](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-A.html#A) is available in [GNAT](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gnat_rm/Safe_005fLarge.html#Safe_005fLarge) as an implementation defined attribute for compatibility with Ada 83. The [Ada 95 Rationale](http://www.adaic.com/standards/95rat/RAThtml/rat95-p3-g.html#4) offers some insights about the change in the discussion on "Safe Range".